# Functional react component not updating when form is submitted

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a functional component (using redux hooks) that edits a note made by the user, everything seems to work just fine but every time I submit the form with the changes it reloads itself and nothing changes, it's like the submit function isn't running every line of code. I separated the content in another function outside the element and the same happens.

Another problem I have (but it's not my main concern) is that I want the value of the inputs to hold the original value of the notes, so the user can edit them without cleaning them up completely.

This is the functional component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";

const submitFunction = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const hystory = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    hystory.push("/")
    return () => { dispatch({ type: "EDIT_NOTE", id, updates: {data}})}
}

const editNote = ({id, title, body}) => {

    const [note, setNote] = useState({
        newTitle : title,
        newBody: body
    });

   
    const onTitleChange = (e) => {
        setNote({...note, newTitle : e.target.value });
    }

    const onBodyChange = (e) => {
        setNote({...note, newBody : e.target.value })
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDeafult();
        submitFunction({note, id});
    }
    return(
        <div>
        <Header />
        <h1>Edit your note</h1>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} name="editForm">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input onChange={onTitleChange} name="title" type="text" value={note.newTitle} />
            <label>Note</label>
            <input onCanPlay={onBodyChange} name="body" type="text" value={note.newBody} />
            <button>Update changes!</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default editNote;
```

And this is the component that calls editNote

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import editNote from "../EditNote"

const ItemList = ({id, title, body}) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const edit = editNote({id, title, body});
    const toEdit = () => {
        history.push("/edit");
        return edit
    }    
    return (
     <div key={id}>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{body}</p>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_NOTE", id})}>Delete</button>
        <button onClick={toEdit}>Edit</button>
    </div>
)}


export default ItemList;
```

I can't find the problem so it's hard to debug.

I thought that maybe the problem is that I'm using a functional component instead of a Class so I made a Class version, however, it has the same problem but at least it allows me to put the input's value as the original one.

This is the class version

```
class EditNote extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBody = this.onChangeBody.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.id,
            newTitle : this.props.title,
            newBody : this.props.body,
            error : ""
        }
    }

    onChangeTitle(e){
        const newTitle = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ newTitle })
    }

    onChangeBody(e){
        const newBody = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ newBody })
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
        <h1>Edit your note</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input onChange={this.onChangeTitle} name="title" type="text" value={this.state.newTitle}/>
            <label>Note</label>
            <input onChange={this.onChangeBody} name="body" type="text" value={this.state.newBody}/>
            <button>Update changes!</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default EditNote
```

////////EDIT///////////

Someone said that I shouldn't return the dispatch function as I did, so changed that but it still isn't working.

(note is the const made by useState where the edited note is stored)

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDeafult();
        console.log(note);
    const hystory = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch({ type: "EDIT_NOTE", id, updates: {note}})
    hystory.push("/")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks such as `useHistory` and `useDispatch` can only be called directly inside the body of a function component.  Calling them in the `submitFunction` function violates the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

There are some other things here that are a bit...confused.  `editNote` appears to be a function component, so it should be named `EditNote`.  Your variable `edit` created from `const edit = editNote({id, title, body});` is some JSX (React HTML) code.  On clicking the "Edit" button, you call `toEdit` which returns `edit`.  An event handler shouldn't return anything.  What are you trying to accomplish by returning some JSX code here.

You also need to think about how you want to use the router here.  You don't *need* to use it at all.  You could control whether or not the `EditNote` component is shown based on the state.  If the router is your "single source of truth", you might want to navigate to a URL like `/edit/${id}` and the render component for that route would load the `EditNote` for the correct note by selecting from redux based on the `id`.  I see you dispatching changes to redux, but I don't see you selecting data from redux anywhere here.

Answer (score 0):

why do you return a function in submitFunction?

```js
return () => { dispatch({ type: "EDIT_NOTE", id, updates: {data}})}
```

that function will not run.

you should be try

```js
const submitFunction = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const hystory = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch({ type: "EDIT_NOTE", id, updates: {data}})
    hystory.push("/")
}
```

and move submitFunction to inside editNote component

Comment: I returned  a function because I saw it in a redux hooks tutorial, but now I changed the code as you said and the page still refreshes and the console.log does not run neither the state changes as is supposed ti do.

Comment: @luciagarciaalcuadrado e.preventDeafult(); => e. preventDefault();